# When creating generic class objects I am getting null. Why?

Tags: java, generics

I am getting null value while creating the `generic class objects`. Please help me to get solution for that.

```
public class ObjectifyGenericDao<T> {
    protected Class<T> clazz;

    public T getByProperty(String propName, Object propValue) {
        // Which is returning null
        System.out.println(this.clazz);
    }
}
```

I am accessing the object like this

```
ObjectifyGenericDao<Users> dao = new ObjectifyGenericDao<Users>(Users.class);
Users user = dao.getByProperty("user_id", userId);
```

Comment: Have you assigned something to the clazz member? It is not done in you example code.

Comment: Did you debug your code at least once?

Comment: Class-naming is strange: an instance of `Users` class (which IS already strange) is called `user`. It has nothing to do with the actual problem, but can be a great source of further issues )

Comment: I don't even see any return-statement in `getByProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

how does it even compile? You are not returning anything from this method declaring a return type.
Please would you post more of the clas? There is no constructor.

Comment: must have been cut off for the sake of brevity